# How to use correlated union types for a strictly typed event emitter

Tags: typescript

I’m implementing a custom event emitter module, which requires the possible event names and payloads to be defined in a generic type parameter.

The usage looks like this:

```js
interface MyEventPayloadMapping = {
  event1: string;
  event2: void;
}

const emitter = createEventEmitter<MyEventPayloadMapping>();
emitter.on('event1', (payload: string) => {});
emitter.on('event2', () => {});
```

The type definition of `EventEmitter` is the following:

```js
type PayloadOneArg<T> = undefined extends T ? [T?] : [T]; 
type PayloadArgs<T> = T extends undefined ? [] : PayloadOneArg<T>; // allow zero, one optional or exactly one argument

type Listener<Arguments> = (...args: PayloadArgs<Arguments>) => void;

interface EventEmitter<T> {
    on<K extends keyof T>(eventName:K, listener: Listener<T[K]>): void;
}
```

Now I’ve encountered an issue when using multiple instances of `EventEmitter` which partially overlap with their event payload mapping.

```js
interface PayloadA {
    readonly foo: number;
    readonly bar: string;
}

interface PayloadB {
    readonly foo: number;
    readonly baz: boolean;
}

type EmitterA = EventEmitter<PayloadA>;
type EmitterB = EventEmitter<PayloadB>;

interface ModuleA {
    readonly type: 'a';
    readonly on: EmitterA['on'];
}

interface ModuleB {
    readonly type: 'b';
    readonly on: EmitterB['on'];
}

function doStuff(mod: ModuleA | ModuleB): void {
    if (mod.type === 'a') {
      mod.on('foo', () => {}); // works
    } else {
      mod.on('foo', () => {}); // works
    }
    mod.on('foo', () => {}); // doesn’t work
}
```

This produces the error

```
This expression is not callable.
  Each member of the union type '(<K extends keyof PayloadA>(eventName: K, listener: Listener<PayloadA[K]>) => void) | (<K extends keyof PayloadB>(eventName: K, listener: Listener<PayloadB[K]>) => void)' has signatures, but none of those signatures are compatible with each other.
```

After creating [issue at the typescript project](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/50182) it was pointed out that an approach to solve this has been implemented in [this pull request](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109). I have some troubles understanding the description of this pull request and applying the concept to my use-case.

My first attempt is the following:

```js
type EventNameToListenerMap<T> = { [P in keyof T]: { name: P, listener: Listener<T[P]>} }

interface EventEmitter<T> {
    on<K extends keyof T>(eventName: EventNameToListenerMap<T>[K]['name'], listener: EventNameToListenerMap<T>[K]['listener']): void;
}
```

But I still get the same error. [Here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.8.0-beta#code/C4TwDgpgBACghiANgezgEwPIDsIEEBOA5gDwAqAfFALxQCuWaEAZgJY5pQQAewEDAzlFJQA-FADapEQF0oALgmlpAbgBQoSLAQp0BQvzKUaw7rwF0GzNhA5jxshfCSpMOPYeVQA9F6hxEKADuUABeEPjIADRQyDgxYMAssf4x+JxccADGwIggMXFwRLQAtnzAqurg0AAyLPxm4cR6JWX8RlAAFAB0PYX6jtouegbNpVjAbQCU1JQAbsgsaGqVmgCis2UAcnClpMi19XzhALJwYIbUUADeEjBQbFAA1hAgyExC0go3WDsQjtGIOoNfAKA7AsjiGDScgAXygMIqbF4+CYWWg6zKq2KLGAyIuV1UUCJ+WIAGl0mY0IJnq93hQOhANuNtqUFBjmb89mCjvhTucKOJSdJxAByH6lEXSAFAnlspnAFkQLkynC8s6GQXCkWAw6qyWTBTzRZqBGqJHhVGZaBOHRoXDXQnE-AQdCxXJQJjIZAKLAlABG4TUxKgztdWHdfsKCnq+DYhBNiPGFrRWmc6AAQg7g6G0G68p7vVBfcUA-gg06Xbnw3lIyEFH6vYgXVgEyt0djceF7TR2cAsTi8TahuQ1Bp2wPwpme-L+538MQhxmR4nkZboMdkGhaE37QTs5W81AxwoRXAReWiTnD7E2R3kbhRbFJa3zSiUxut03M3uK2H3ceoBFP1z0dS8D2rfJbwnfB00fLBn1UU0mHobIkiwKBcwAZWAWgmCYDpik3BQP23PAoAAHygEivwNKAjQ4H8iRYd4CM3Lox2oKgaFPEVpkY4lCLQLpYg6EUCxFaIOmmKhKCuGFJk8HwoECZB8EefhQPhThEH4aB+KJQThKwUTxMk6TZPkxTfBUtSNODBFg0MkSxK9CTOnM65LO8XxcwgfgsEATAJgGU1THkQoA) is a playground link.

So the question is, can someone explain the concept of the solution introduced by the typescript pull request? And maybe additionally provide some hints how it could be applied for my use-case?

Comment: If the question is "explain the concept" then this is probably a duplicate of a bunch of [other answers I've made about this](https://www.google.com/search?q=jcalz+47109+30581+site:stackoverflow.com) and I doubt I can do much better than those plus the text of the pull request itself.  If you want to know how to apply it to your example code then [this is how I'd do it](https://tsplay.dev/mLqoVW). Do you want me to write this solution up as an answer?  Let me know how to proceed.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and the concrete example to help me with my use-case. I’ve read through a couple of threads regarding this topic and I at least understood that the function that is calling `on()` needs to be generic. At first I thought it would be enough to only adjust the `EventEmitter` interface and the type of the `on()` method. I still struggle a little bit to understand the whole concept, why the additional Map type is needed. I’ve also encountered another issue, using this approach it is no longer possible to use  `type` as a discriminator, see tsplay.dev/NDyoxm.

Comment: It's not really feasible for me to address additional issues in comment sections. If you want to open a new question for it I might be able to look at it.  For this question as asked above, would my solution be an acceptable answer for you? Or am I missing the point of this question?

Comment: You are right, your solution does answer my initial question. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general approach to this sort of thing, as described in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109), is to make some simple mapping interface like

```
interface PayloadMap {
    a: PayloadA,
    b: PayloadB
}
```

and then represent your operation as a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) function over a a key type parameter `K` [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to the keys of that mapping interface, and where the parameters to this function are represented as a *distributive object type* that is defined in terms of this mapping interface.  Like this:

```
type Module<K extends keyof PayloadMap = keyof PayloadMap> = { [P in K]:
    { readonly type: P, readonly on: OnEventEmitter<PayloadMap[P]> }
}[K]
```

where I've defined `OnEventEmitter` as

```
interface OnEventEmitter<T> {
    <P extends keyof T>(
        eventName: P,
        listener: (...args: PayloadArgs<T[P]>) => void
    ): void;
}
```

The `Module<K>` type is a distributive object type because it is a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) into which we immediately [index into](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html).   When `K` is `"a"` then you get your `ModuleA` type, and when `K` is `"b"` then you get your `ModuleB` type.  And, importantly, the type `Module` by itself is therefore a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) corresponding exactly to your original `ModuleA | ModuleB` type.

Anyway, now you can write `doStuff()` and it compiles:

```
function doStuff<K extends keyof PayloadMap>(mod: Module<K>): void {
    mod.on('foo', (x) => { x.toFixed() }); // okay
}
```

And you can call it, even with a union of `ModuleA` and `ModuleB` input:

```
declare const moduleA: Module<"a">
declare const moduleB: Module<"b">
doStuff(Math.random() < 0.5 ? moduleA : moduleB);
```

---

The `doStuff()` implementation works because `mod.on()` is seen to be of a *single* generic function type  `<"foo">(eventName: "foo", listener: (...args: PayloadArgs<PayloadMap[K]["foo"]>) => void) => void`.  If `doStuff()` were not generic, or if `Module<K>` were expressed as some type that was opaque to the compiler (such as `Extract<ModuleA | ModuleB, {type: K}>`), then you'd get compile errors trying to call `mod.on()`:

```
// Don't do this
type OpaqueModule<K extends keyof PayloadMap> =
    Extract<Module<"a"> | Module<"b">, { type: K }>

function doOpaqueStuff<K extends keyof PayloadMap>(mod: OpaqueModule<K>): void {
    mod.on('foo', (x) => { x.toFixed() }); // error
    // none of those signatures are compatible with each other
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.7.4#code/C4TwDgpgBACghiANgezgEwPIDsIEEBOA5gDwAqAfFALxQCuWaEAZgJY5pQQAewEDAzlFJQA-FADapEQF0oALgmlpAbgBQoSLAQp0BQvzKUaw7rwF0GzNhA5jxshfCSpMOPYeVQA9F6hxEKADuUABeEPjIADRQyDgxYMAssf4x+JxccADGwIggMXFwRLQAtnzAqqpsvPhMWdDYAKIAbmUNxSzA1YZQAN6qUANQxDDpZmiCANYQIMhMQuQAFP2DKxAtWMAAcnCljpHLKwOILPxm4QoLAHTXhfqO2i56BqTiMNLkAJTUlE3ILGgHKAfBS-f5qAC+FSq4VqmWgTh0aFwvUB+Ag6FiuSgTGQyAUWBKACNwmoVmiMVgsYTCgpTvg2IQIVCNjC6lpnOgAEIosnotCYvI4vFQAnFYn4UmDcn8yl5akhBSE3GIdFYJmVFk1NkIlwAWTgYB5gzg9w5SP2K0JpsRnNUkPU4GguuQaFoKuIAGlRnxxlApjM5jr0PrDTR-bN2YiQ0ZehIRmwoB7pHJAT0oNKBVANBA9um+ZnYgpGutgG0Ol0g2gQ693lBIeDxEmKqomPRskksFB+QBlYC0JhMT3e8zhwMPYMGxbFF0KZ2u90ez4gv4cPoradoS6xBYAciFO+iCy4XyolDTXEuwGQADEWFwbAsvuCPp4fDEJgg7apGJlEIVoJksSnFAG5ungs4umBxAAERwNB5DfhAv7-lAgFYMBoEqpyEHzhAMGEvB37IL2-ZMAs+rAAAFpc+BwAwyDFI+QxQAADJcACsoggZBKrIgomEQJyL4VG+AAisQ7sAXbIFmlEnA6mgYGAcAAI60BAc5QV6pg+pM0wRpW0bUICDQ8LR2TEJp7qwfBUAAD5QFZeHQQR5DRGm2YKF64IIS2baJLE0lKap6kkQOQ46SO+ljma0YLBuRbKWpGk8Xhi7AlAoKroCG5blgu77oex7fLGF5Xre95oExz6vr44QRPggJvlgsTQBGVHIPw0D8CwhBYHAfZooIKGAcUymJISKpQIEHSUZwWRzcgVHhF+qhAA)

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation. This really helped me to understand the solution approach. Although it seems to be quite inconvenient to use and might cause other issues, like narrowing using a discriminator, but that is a different topic.